# How can I set an environment variable based on pre-rewritten URI or post-rewritten query parameter?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress, gzip, rewrite

So there's a file in WordPress, `wp-content/blogs.php`, that serves files uploaded through WordPress. There's a `RewriteRule` in the WP `.htaccess` that rewrites URLs of the format `www.example.com/files/11/01/filename.mp3` to URLs of the format `www.example.com/.../wp-content/blogs.php?file=filename.mp3`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-content/blogs.php?file=$2 [L]
```

So here's the problem: we have gzip turned on for PHP files. I need to turn it off based on the query parameter `file`, on `blogs.php`. (Not just because you're not supposed to gzip binaries, but because gzipping `.mp3` creates severe problems for the Quicktime plugin in Firefox on both PC and Mac.)

But the following `SetEnvIf` isn't applied to any files served through `blogs.php` - the `Request_URI` always ends in `.php`.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

The following fixes the problem by turning off gzip on all files served through `blogs.php`:

```
<Location /michael/blah/wp-content/blogs.php>        
     SetEnv no-gzip
</Location>
```

But it's not a good solution, because I want non-binary files served through `blogs.php` to be gzipped. So what I really want is a way to get the *original* URI, not the rewritten URI, because the original URI does end in `.mp3`. Or, I need to access the query parameter at the end of the rewritten URI (ie. `file=filename.mp3`).

For instance, something like this would work, if it existed, which it doesn't:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Original_Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

It looks like there's a variable `THE_REQUEST` that would work in a `RewriteRule`, but it doesn't seem available to `SetEnvIf`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the environment from mod_rewrite, including turning off gzip:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=(.*)\.mp3$
RewriteRule ^(./)?files/(.) wp-content/blogs.php?file=$2 [L,E=no-gzip:1]
```

The first `RewriteCond` may not be necessary, but the last rule (the E flag) should do the trick in your setup regardless.

HTH.